# Upload file to asset folder in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, file, pdf, upload

I would like to 'upload' a pdf file to asset folder. I am able to display a pdf file from asset folder with pdf-viewer. For my project (which should only run locally) I would like to have the possibility to upload a file to the asset folder.

My version information:

```
Angular CLI: 11.0.2
Node: 15.3.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.0.2
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.2
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.2
@angular/cdk                    11.0.1
@angular/material               11.0.1
@schematics/angular             11.0.2
@schematics/update              0.1100.2
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I solved this issue by myself. Just take a look at this page:

Chapter: Render local PDF file

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer

Install to your Angular App PdfViewerModule by running command:

```
npm install ng2-pdf-viewer
```

Add the import to your App-Module.ts

```
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
```

Add this to imports in App-Module.ts

```
imports: [
    PdfViewerModule
  ],
```

Add following template to your html file of any component:

```
<input (change)="onFileSelected()" type="file" id="file">
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc" [render-text]="true" style="display: block;"></pdf-viewer>
```

Add following code to .ts file of your component.

```
pdfSrc: string;

onFileSelected() {
    let $img: any = document.querySelector('#file');

    if (typeof (FileReader) !== 'undefined') {
     let reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (e: any) => {
        this.pdfSrc = e.target.result;
      };

      reader.readAsArrayBuffer($img.files[0]);
    }
 }
```

Now you can choose a pdf file from your local file system and it is immediately shown on your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload anything into in any folder without using server side programming. Most Angular applications are run on node server. This server is not programmed to take a file and put in any folder as static asset.

You have to write your own server on node and configure it so that it will return index.html to browser with angular code bundled. Now in this SPA, if you upload any file, make a http request to endpoint of same server. Define a controller which takes this file and put it in any public folder.

Better approach is, decouple your frontend and backend. Run your angular app at localhost:4200. Run your server app at some other port(You can create a server using node, Java, Golang etc... which can handle HTTP Requests). Send your file as FORMDATA from your angular app using HttpClient to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. But basically that is exactly the way I don't want to do it ;) Is there no poissibility to select a file from your local file system through an angular web page and copy it to the assets folder?